# How to write a SQL query if I want to get value with multiple codes in single column?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a column name `Generic_Code` in a SQL Server table `FAMPRD`.

This column has values like `'00001'`. Sometimes column has values like `'00001', '00002'`. And sometimes like this `'00001', '00002', '00034', '00052'` in a single cell value.

Here is a sample data of my table:

| Prd_Code | Prd_Desc1 | Packing | Company_Name | Generic_Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 701010001 | NIXIDE-500 TAB | 1*10 | MEDLEY PHARMA.PVT.LTD. | '00001','00002' |
| 701010013 | CASH | 1 | 7 CLOCK | '00001', '00002', '00034', '00052' |
| 701010016 | LIQUID PARAFIN 100ML | 1*100ML | COMMON PRODUCT | '00003' |
| 701010017 | NAPZAC EYE DROP |  | 7 CLOCK | '00001' |
| 701010018 | NCIN |  | 7 CLOCK | '00001' |
| 701010019 | REG-MPS TAB | 10 TAB | 7 CLOCK | '00001' |
| 701010020 | S |  | 7 CLOCK | '00001' |
| 701010021 | EDARABID INJ | 1*20ML | INTAS PHRMA. | '00001' |
| 701010022 | GLOSILK SOAP | 1*75GM | AARISE BIOCARE PVT | '00001' |

**Column data types**

All columns are `varchar`.

Now I have 2 questions:

**Question #1**

I want write a SQL query where if I want to search `'00001', '00002'` then all data which includes `'00001'` and `'00002'` should be returned.

It's like a strict filter that if and only if value `'00001'` and `'00002'` exists then return that data but if exists more than that it won't return.

Example:

- Only get data when only `'00001'` and `'00002'` exists.
- If value is `'00001', '00002', '00034', '00052'` then not needed.

Expected result:

| Prd_Code | Prd_Desc1 | Packing | Company_Name | Generic_Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 701010001 | NIXIDE-500 TAB | 1*10 | MEDLEY PHARMA.PVT.LTD. | '00001','00002' |

**Question #2**

Another query I want to write is if I search for '00001', '00002' then all data which includes `'00001'` or `'00002'` should be returned. It should fetch all data if `00001` or `00002` exists in any data.

Expected result :

| Prd_Code | Prd_Desc1 | Packing | Company_Name | Generic_Code |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 701010001 | NIXIDE-500 TAB | 1*10 | MEDLEY PHARMA.PVT.LTD. | '00001','00002' |
| 701010013 | CASH | 1 | 7 CLOCK | '00001', '00002', '00034', '00052' |
| 701010017 | NAPZAC EYE DROP |  | 7 CLOCK | '00001' |
| 701010018 | NCIN |  | 7 CLOCK | '00001' |
| 701010019 | REG-MPS TAB | 10 TAB | 7 CLOCK | '00001' |
| 701010020 | S |  | 7 CLOCK | '00001' |
| 701010021 | EDARABID INJ | 1*20ML | INTAS PHRMA. | '00001' |
| 701010022 | GLOSILK SOAP | 1*75GM | AARISE BIOCARE PVT | '00001' |

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Abra, There are lots of columns actually but I am typing datatypes whichever I shown in sample data above.

Comment: Maybe [regular expressions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/scripting/search-text-with-regular-expressions?view=sql-server-ver16) is appropriate?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: @ThomA So how shall I show sql data ? by Drawing characters?

Comment: @Abra yes all I want is to get result. RE will work.

Comment: No, that would be *worse*. As *text*. Ideally DDL and DML statements, but minimally a markdown table.

Comment: The real problem, however, appears to be your design; it's denormalised/ *Never* store delimited data in your database. Fix that problem first and likely other problems you're facing and simplified or disappear.

Comment: @ThomA The problem is I didn't make the table, but I am getting data from elsewhere.  Issue is that I have to make it work with this sort of data because I am going to get it in future repeatedly.

Comment: @ThomA a markdown table, I always wonder how people make such a good table representation. Thanks anyways. I replace images in a mean time.

Comment: That you are getting that data doesn't mean you don't normalise it when you consume it, @bonny .

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, I'd advise a read of this: [Is storing a delimited list in a database column really that bad?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3653462/1048425) (Spoiler, the answer is yes).

Next I'd advise a read of [Divided We Stand: The SQL of Relational Division](https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/databases/sql-server/t-sql-programming-sql-server/divided-we-stand-the-sql-of-relational-division/), this covers a wide range of approaches to relational division (what you are trying to do) for each of the scenarios you've covered.

Finally, the approach I would take is to first split your values into rows using `STRING_SPLIT` then do your equality checks, then roll these back up to the original row level, something like:

```
DECLARE @Values VARCHAR(1000) = '00001,00002';
WITH SplitInput AS
(
    SELECT  DISTINCT ss.value
    FROM    STRING_SPLIT(@Values, ',') AS ss
)
SELECT sd.GenericCode,
        ContainsAny = CASE WHEN COUNT(si.value) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
        ContainsAll = CASE WHEN COUNT(si.value) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SplitInput) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
        ContainsOnly = CASE WHEN COUNT(si.value) = COUNT(*) AND COUNT(si.value) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SplitInput) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
FROM    #SampleData AS sd
        CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(sd.GenericCode, ',') AS ss
        LEFT JOIN SplitInput AS si
            ON si.value = ss.value
GROUP BY sd.GenericCode;
```

For a sample data set this returns something like the following for the input above (00001,00002)

| GenericCode | ContainsAny | ContainsAll | ContainsOnly |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 00001 | 1 | 0 | 0 |
| 00001,00002 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 00001,00002,00034 | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| 00052 | 0 | 0 | 0 |

- **Contains Any** = Any of the supplied values match any of the values stored
- **Contains All** = All of the supplied values match the stored values, does not matter if there are additional stored values
- **Contains Only** = All of the supplied values are matched with no remainder (i.e. exact match)

Hopefully you can adapt this to suit your different scenarios.

---

**Full Code example**

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #SampleData;
CREATE TABLE #SampleData (GenericCode VARCHAR(100));
INSERT #SampleData(GenericCode)
VALUES ('00001'),('00001,00002'),('00001,00034'), ('00001,00002,00034,00052');
GO
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS #SampleProcedure; -- Using temp proc for simplicity of demo code
GO
CREATE PROCEDURE #SampleProcedure @Values VARCHAR(1000)
AS
BEGIN
    WITH SplitInput AS
    (
        SELECT  DISTINCT ss.value
        FROM    STRING_SPLIT(@Values, ',') AS ss
    )
    SELECT sd.GenericCode,
            ContainsAny = CASE WHEN COUNT(si.value) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
            ContainsAll = CASE WHEN COUNT(si.value) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SplitInput) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END,
            ContainsOnly = CASE WHEN COUNT(si.value) = COUNT(*) AND COUNT(si.value) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM SplitInput) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
    FROM    #SampleData AS sd
            CROSS APPLY STRING_SPLIT(sd.GenericCode, ',') AS ss
            LEFT JOIN SplitInput AS si
                ON si.value = ss.value
    GROUP BY sd.GenericCode;

END
GO
EXECUTE #SampleProcedure @Values = '00001';
EXECUTE #SampleProcedure @Values = '00001,00002';
EXECUTE #SampleProcedure @Values = '00001,00002,00034';
EXECUTE #SampleProcedure @Values = '00001,00002,00034,00052';
EXECUTE #SampleProcedure @Values = '00035,00055';
```

Comment: Ok , I try it and let you know..

Comment: i'm not sure if it's relevant, but OPs data contains quotes around values, maybe it should be handled here

Comment: I did consider that, but don't think it is relevant to the concept being demonstrated, and escaping the quotes (in my opinion) obfuscates the example without actually adding any meaning. It might make it very slightly more relevant to this one example, but less clear to any future readers so went with clarity over an exact sample data match. [Here is an example with quotes](https://dbfiddle.uk/PAN669U9) in case how to deal with quotes is not clear in the above